# Promise.all result fires before actions succeed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I'm searching and searching solution on Stackoverflow and Github but 1.5 day is not enough - I don't see where I'm making mistake. I have following code of my component where I would like to fetch data from two endpoints and after store updates I console log something.

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData()
    }

  fetchData(){
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    Promise.all([
      dispatch(getTodos()),
      dispatch(getPhotos())
    ])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('I did everything!');
    });

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Something</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(ExampleComponent)
```

And here are my actions...

```
export function getPhotos() {
  return function(dispatch) {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('photos')
        dispatch({type: 'PHOTOS_REQUEST_SUCCESS',payload: response})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(photosRequestError(err))
      })
  }
}

export function getTodos() {
  return function(dispatch){
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .then(
        (response) => {
        console.log('todos')
        dispatch({type: 'TODOS_REQUEST_SUCCESS', payload: response})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(todosRequestError(err))
      })
  }
}
```

In console I get "I did everything", "todos", "photos". How should I modify my code to update store first and then log "I did everything" in console?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promises themselves so that the chaining apply synchronous, so try adding `return` to  `axios.get('endpoint/url')` in both functions.